# Does it makes sense to apply feature scaling on timestamp

Tags: feature-scaling, preprocessing

I was wondering if it makes sense to apply normal standardization on a feature like timestamp ?
The data that I process are network packets.

Thank you

Comment: Could you expand on what you want to use this feature to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For time series analysis.  **Yes**

But, turning data into a computable object for using in the ML computation?  **No**

Using the data as a feature.  Then, **Yes**

I would give you a general time series example:

Consider the number of days in months. The irregularity causes friction while analyzing the model.

Consider this:
[image]

So, such type of transformations would be helpful which analyzing time series', which can help reduce friction in the models sensibly.
[Link of the explanation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/165166/number-of-days-in-a-monthly-forecast/165169#165169)